# I have tried MAX and Group By but still got repeated entry instead of latest result

Tags: sql

```
Name(Nvarchar)(max)      Datetime(nvarchar)(max)       Value 
Rob                      10/08/2020 07:20:40                        10
Rob                      10/08/2020 14:08:30                         20
Rob                      10/08/2020 20:10:45                         23
Rob                      11/08/2020 10:30:45.                        5
Rob                      11/08/2020 18:20:55.                        7
```

Result should be:

```
Rob                      10/08/2020 20:10:45.                       23
Rob                      11/08/2020 18:20:55                         7
```

I need latest entry by Rob on each day.

Comment: The use of MAX is more referring to the function than the limitations of the data type. You'll have to use MAX(Datetime) with GROUP BY to get what you're after - See link (https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-function.php)

Comment: "`Datetime(nvarchar)(max)`" -- first fix this capital error! Always use appropriate data types! For a timestamp a string type is not appropriate. Use some date/time type instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer** - To include values against latest date

```
WITH [TempTable] AS (
    SELECT name, MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [Datetime], 131)) as MaxDate
    FROM t
    GROUP BY name, CAST(CONVERT(datetime, [Datetime], 131) As date)
)
SELECT ntt.name, ntt.MaxDate, t.Value
FROM NewTempTable ntt
INNER JOIN t ON ntt.name = t.name
    AND ntt.MaxDate = CAST(CONVERT(datetime, t.Datetime, 131) As date)
```

**Original Answer**

Based on what you're asking, I think what you're lacking is the group by on each day without time (seeing that you want the max entry for each day). Assuming you're working with Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT name, MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [Datetime], 131))
FROM t
GROUP BY name, CAST(CONVERT(datetime, [Datetime], 131) As date);
```

Answer updated to allow for NVARCHAR > Datetime conversion - Preferably, this conversion should be be done at a table level rather than within the query to improve performance of the query. Reference code for the datetime conversion (i.e. 131) can be found on the Microsoft website ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Comment: Daytime and is in Nvarchar(MAX) so when I use casi it throws errors of conversion failed when converting string to datetime.

Comment: Answer has been updated to allow for nvarchar to datetime conversion. =)

Comment: Hi Mate, I have run query and it is just works fine but when I add value column it repeated rows based on group by. I only need the latest date and all the value in that row.

Comment: Hey Jak, I've updated my answer with the new query that you can use. The reason why it looks a lot longer is because you have to first group the names to get the latest date before you'll be able to obtain all values against that date. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select name, max(datetime)
from t
group by name;
```

If you want one row per *name*, that should be the only key in the `group by`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the reply but with same name I want to get the max date time for 11/08/2020 and so on.I want to get the max entry on date with the same name every day. When I have run this query group by doesn’t filter date we it’s latest entry.

Comment: @Jak . . . I believe this answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, MAX(convert(datetime,[Datetime])) maxDateTime
FROM temp
GROUP BY name , convert(date ,[Datetime]);

OR

SELECT name, MAX([Datetime]) maxDateTime
FROM temp
GROUP BY name , convert(date ,[Datetime]);
```

Both of them are correct